# Restrict users from creating new taxonomy term if it does not exist

Tags: taxonomy-terms, ajax

i have a content type "Recipe" . And i have a "field_cusine" with type "Term reference" and widget is "Autocomplete term widget (tagging)".

Now while adding the content as an admin. If i add a term which does not exist it will be added .

I want to restrict this for other "authenticated users" on my site. They should see the "Autocomplete term widget (tagging)" but should not be able to add new terms.

Any clue.
thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Disable new terms (free tagging) with Taxonomies?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/59159/how-to-disable-new-terms-free-tagging-with-taxonomies)

Comment: yes this can be the answer to my question. but i want to restrict just site registered users from adding terms in to my vocab. (not the admin or certain roles )